# Add to C++ application C# GUI

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

I would like to add my C++ application a C# .NET GUI .
My C++ application is very simple but I have a some Pointer and Reference .

What is the Best way C# will recognize this pointer and Reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways, here are some, and it depends on your taste and on your project.

a) Use COM interop, if your C++ project is written in COM.

b) Use COM interop, you can write COM wrappers to your C++ application and use it from C#.

c) Use C++/CLI, that is, convert your project to become a Managed C++ application and create managed classes in C++ that use your C++ code.
You can also write a managed C++ dll that loads your C++ dll or static library.

d) Use P INVOKE C calls, exports DLL C functions from your C++ code that work with your C++ class, call the C functions from C# using [dllimport] attribute.
You can use type IntPtr and the better and safer SafeHandle to express pointers and references.

All ways have good things and drawbacks, but every listed tehcnique need a "middle layer", you cannot call C++ code directly from C#.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to use the functionality written in C++ program  in a C# based UI application.

You can do this by creating a C++/CLI based dll. C++/CLI can call C++ code easily and C# can easily call C++/CLI code. In this way you can use functionality written in C++ in a C# based program

For all possible ways see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/borisj/archive/2006/09/28/769708.aspx) post